# Change Map language dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using AgmCoreModule to load google map.
Is it possible to change map language dynamically when language is selected?

I am able to set default language on load of map using code below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      libraries: ["places"],
      language: 'de'
    }),
    ...
    ]
})
```

But what I actually needed is to change language of map on language selected from dropdown.
**OR**
How do I set language in MapsAPILoader?

```
this._mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
...
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
          apiKey: 'yourmapapikey',
          language: 'iw',
      })
  ],
```

iw - For Hebrew, 
check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) for your language.

Comment: Sorry @Maciej Treder, but snippet in my question is same as your answer.. This does not provide me answer. I want to dynamically change language based on language selected from dropdown.. Above is what i was already able to make up.

Comment: ohh.. sorry @MaciejTreder, wrong tagged..supposed  to tag Ido_Hightech

Answer (score 1):

in order to replace the language you should at first delete the script and google maps,
then generate it again and wait a while till it's reloaded
you can do it like that:

```
async loadScript() {
var oldScript = document.getElementById("agmGoogleMapsApiScript");
if (oldScript !== null) {
  oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
  delete google.maps;
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
v=3&key={{YourApiKey}}&region=israel&language= 
{{language}}';
script.id = "agmGoogleMapsApiScript";
document.body.appendChild(script);
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
```

then you should reload the agm-core map, you can do it by stepping out of the component.

don't forget to declare google, like that:

```
declare var google: any;
```

worked for me, hope it helps :)